# Object Variable type e expressions

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de montar uma expression no ssis que retorne true ou false numa variavel do tipo object :

basicamente seria algo como
em sql 12 in (14,25,45,12,54) porem na expression ao inves de uma lista seria algo como

```
numero in objectVariable
```

Comment: Poderia criar um exemplo mais elaborado do que você deseja? Não entendi.

Comment: eu tenho uma variavel do tipo objeto que recebe valores do result de uma query, logo ela tem varias linhas como resultado. eu gostaria de fazer uma expression pra saber se um numero n pertence a coleção de numeros retornados dentro da variavel caso tenha esse numero ele ira executar a ação A se não a ação B @gmsantos

Comment: Acho que sua necessidade pode ser simplificada com alguma derived column combinado com um lookup ou conditional split do que uma expression obscura como essa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você for capaz de gerar a sequência de valores com vírgulas no início de no fim, pode usar a função [`CHARINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) para localizar o número.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE CHARINDEX( 
        ',54,' , 
        ',14,25,45,12,54,'
    )
```

Ou:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE CHARINDEX(
        ',' + CAST(numero as VARCHAR) + ',' , 
        ',14,25,45,12,54,'
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Se for no SQL Server 2012, você pode montar uma micro-tabela que funciona como um array:

```
DECLARE @ListaDeIDs TABLE(IDs int);
INSERT INTO @ListaDeIDs
VALUES(14),(25),(45),(12),(54);
SELECT IDs FROM @ListaDeIDs;
GO
```

Aí a comparação fica assim:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE 12 IN (SELECT IDs FROM @ListaDeIDs)
```

Comment: acredito que nao era esta minha duvida, minha duvida seria como montar uma expressão no sql servert integration services onde verifica se existe um numero tal dentro de uma variavel do tipo object que recebeu os valores de um result ser de multiplas linhas.

Comment: E o Integration Services não aceita T-SQL? Esquisito.